# TKinter как установить начальное положение слайдера в определенное значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день суть в следующем есть шкала со слайдером, как установить при запуске программы стартовое значение слайдера на определенное значение, пробовал метод set() но как я понимаю он находится в цикле и значение передаваемое со шкалы всегда будет то которое установлено в этом методе.

Код:

```
def draw():
    main_window = Tk()                                               
    main_window.title('Манипулятор')                                 
    main_window.geometry('800x600')                                  
    main_window.iconbitmap(r'C:/Users/Lukya/Desktop/icon1.ico')   
    main_window['bg']='#414977'                        

    Degree1 = Scale(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, length=300,from_=0,to=180, tickinterval=20, resolution=1, command=lambda value: send(1, value))
    Degree2 = Scale(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, length=300,from_=0,to=180, tickinterval=20, resolution=1, command=lambda value: send(2, value))
    Degree3 = Scale(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, length=300,from_=0,to=180, tickinterval=20, resolution=1, command=lambda value: send(3, value))
    Degree4 = Scale(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, length=300,from_=0,to=180, tickinterval=20, resolution=1, command=lambda value: send(4, value))
    Degree5 = Scale(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, length=300,from_=0,to=180, tickinterval=20, resolution=1, command=lambda value: send(5, value)) 

    def create_scale(degree):
        degree['highlightthickness']=0
        degree['bg']='#4c7c9a'
        degree['foreground']='#3a3663'
        degree['troughcolor']='#3a3663'
        degree['orient']=VERTICAL
        degree['length']=300
        degree['bd']=0
        degree['relief']=FLAT
        degree['activebackground']='#c0331f'
        degree['sliderrelief']=GROOVE

    Degree1.set(90)
    Degree2.set(0)
    Degree3.set(105)
    Degree4.set(80)
    Degree5.set(0)


    create_scale(Degree1)
    create_scale(Degree2)
    create_scale(Degree3)
    create_scale(Degree4)
    create_scale(Degree5)

    Degree1.place(x=160,y=150)        
    Degree2.place(x=260,y=150)          
    Degree3.place(x=360,y=150)        
    Degree4.place(x=460,y=150)         
    Degree5.place(x=560,y=150)         

    main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: "пробовал метод set() но как я понимаю он находится в цикле" - в каком цикле?

Comment: Для форматирования кода нужно выделить его весь целиком, и нажать кнопку `{}` в редакторе, а не просто поставить 4 пробела перед первой строкой.

Comment: main_window.mainloop()

Comment: Весь код выше вызова `main_window.mainloop()` не находится в цикле и выполняется один раз. Если конечно у вас функция `draw()` не вызывается в цикле.

Comment: нет функция draw() вызывается единожды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main_window.mainloop()` запускает цикл обработки событий (см. *[Событийно-ориентированное_программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)*), но не делает все что выше его вызова циклом. Сам цикл скрыт внутри метода `mainloop` класса `Tk`. Все что вы делаете до вызова `mainloop` выполняется один раз, там можно делать всю инициализацию, в том числе и установку начальных значений для виджетов.